# What is example output for gcloud firebase test android run

Tags: firebase, firebase-test-lab

My `gcloud firebase test android run` command is stuck uploading the `app-debug-androidTest.apk`.  What is an example of the output for this command once it gets past the following point where it's stuck for me?

```
FirebaseTestLabPlayground[master]15:40:36 gcloud firebase test android run \
> --project locuslabs-android-sdk \
> --app app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk \
> --test app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk \
> --device model=Pixel2,version=27,locale=en_US,orientation=portrait \
> --verbosity debug 
INFO: Test Service endpoint: [None]
INFO: Tool Results endpoint: [None]
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.firebase.test.android.run] with arguments: [--app: "app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk", --device: "[OrderedDict([(u'model', u'Pixel2'), (u'version', u'27'), (u'locale', u'en_US'), (u'orientation', u'portrait')])]", --project: "locuslabs-android-sdk", --test: "app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk", --verbosity: "debug"]

Have questions, feedback, or issues? Get support by visiting:
  https://firebase.google.com/support/

DEBUG: Applying default auto_google_login: True
DEBUG: Applying default performance_metrics: True
DEBUG: Applying default num_flaky_test_attempts: 0
DEBUG: Applying default record_video: True
DEBUG: Applying default timeout: 900
DEBUG: Applying default async: False
INFO: Raw results root path is: [gs://test-lab-bcr7j9th055js-i215tdq3ht0hw/2019-04-19_15:41:26.364106_bmag/]
Uploading [app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk] to Firebase Test Lab...
Uploading [app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk] to Firebase Test Lab...
```

What will likely come next?

Comment: How large are the APKs that you're uploading?

Comment: @P.Davis it was quite big, 164 MB, because it contains many images.  The images are screenshots, they're the admissible screenshots.  We take a screenshot after each test and compare it to the admissible screenshots.  It worked fine for local testing with a physical device.  But I have to come up with a new approach for Firebase Test Lab, maybe upload the images to a temporary bucket using `gsutil` before each test session.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the rest of the transcript in case it helps anyone else who's stuck trying `gcloud firebase test android run` for the first time:

```
FirebaseTestLabPlayground[master]15:40:36 gcloud firebase test android run \
> --project locuslabs-android-sdk \
> --app app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk \
> --test app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk \
> --device model=Pixel2,version=27,locale=en_US,orientation=portrait \
> --verbosity debug 
INFO: Test Service endpoint: [None]
INFO: Tool Results endpoint: [None]
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.firebase.test.android.run] with arguments: [--app: "app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk", --device: "[OrderedDict([(u'model', u'Pixel2'), (u'version', u'27'), (u'locale', u'en_US'), (u'orientation', u'portrait')])]", --project: "locuslabs-android-sdk", --test: "app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk", --verbosity: "debug"]

Have questions, feedback, or issues? Get support by visiting:
  https://firebase.google.com/support/

DEBUG: Applying default auto_google_login: True
DEBUG: Applying default performance_metrics: True
DEBUG: Applying default num_flaky_test_attempts: 0
DEBUG: Applying default record_video: True
DEBUG: Applying default timeout: 900
DEBUG: Applying default async: False
INFO: Raw results root path is: [gs://test-lab-bcr7j9th055js-i215tdq3ht0hw/2019-04-19_15:41:26.364106_bmag/]
Uploading [app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk] to Firebase Test Lab...
Uploading [app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk] to Firebase Test Lab...
Raw results will be stored in your GCS bucket at [https://console.developers.google.com/storage/browser/test-lab-bcr7j9th055js-i215tdq3ht0hw/2019-04-19_15:41:26.364106_bmag/]

DEBUG: TestMatrices.Create request:
<TestingProjectsTestMatricesCreateRequest
 projectId: u'locuslabs-android-sdk'
 requestId: '3c76ca4e247d4b38bf102ffcdbaa637b'
 testMatrix: <TestMatrix
 clientInfo: <ClientInfo
 clientInfoDetails: [<ClientInfoDetail
 key: u'Cloud SDK Version'
 value: '242.0.0'>, <ClientInfoDetail
 key: u'Release Track'
 value: 'GA'>]
 name: u'gcloud'>
 environmentMatrix: <EnvironmentMatrix
 androidDeviceList: <AndroidDeviceList
 androidDevices: [<AndroidDevice
 androidModelId: u'Pixel2'
 androidVersionId: u'27'
 locale: u'en_US'
 orientation: u'portrait'>]>>
 flakyTestAttempts: 0
 resultStorage: <ResultStorage
 googleCloudStorage: <GoogleCloudStorage
 gcsPath: u'gs://test-lab-bcr7j9th055js-i215tdq3ht0hw/2019-04-19_15:41:26.364106_bmag/'>
 toolResultsHistory: <ToolResultsHistory
 projectId: u'locuslabs-android-sdk'>>
 testExecutions: []
 testSpecification: <TestSpecification
 androidInstrumentationTest: <AndroidInstrumentationTest
 appApk: <FileReference
 gcsPath: u'gs://test-lab-bcr7j9th055js-i215tdq3ht0hw/2019-04-19_15:41:26.364106_bmag/app-debug.apk'>
 orchestratorOption: OrchestratorOptionValueValuesEnum(ORCHESTRATOR_OPTION_UNSPECIFIED, 0)
 testApk: <FileReference
 gcsPath: u'gs://test-lab-bcr7j9th055js-i215tdq3ht0hw/2019-04-19_15:41:26.364106_bmag/app-debug-androidTest.apk'>
 testTargets: []>
 disablePerformanceMetrics: False
 disableVideoRecording: False
 testSetup: <TestSetup
 account: <Account
 googleAuto: <GoogleAuto>>
 additionalApks: []
 directoriesToPull: []
 environmentVariables: []
 filesToPush: []>
 testTimeout: u'900s'>>>

DEBUG: TestMatrices.Create response:
<TestMatrix
 clientInfo: <ClientInfo
 clientInfoDetails: [<ClientInfoDetail
 key: u'Cloud SDK Version'
 value: u'242.0.0'>, <ClientInfoDetail
 key: u'Release Track'
 value: u'GA'>]
 name: u'gcloud'>
 environmentMatrix: <EnvironmentMatrix
 androidDeviceList: <AndroidDeviceList
 androidDevices: [<AndroidDevice
 androidModelId: u'Pixel2'
 androidVersionId: u'27'
 locale: u'en_US'
 orientation: u'portrait'>]>>
 projectId: u'locuslabs-android-sdk'
 resultStorage: <ResultStorage
 googleCloudStorage: <GoogleCloudStorage
 gcsPath: u'gs://test-lab-bcr7j9th055js-i215tdq3ht0hw/2019-04-19_15:41:26.364106_bmag/'>
 toolResultsHistory: <ToolResultsHistory
 projectId: u'locuslabs-android-sdk'>>
 state: StateValueValuesEnum(VALIDATING, 1)
 testExecutions: [<TestExecution
 environment: <Environment
 androidDevice: <AndroidDevice
 androidModelId: u'Pixel2'
 androidVersionId: u'27'
 locale: u'en_US'
 orientation: u'portrait'>>
 id: u'matrix-fq9ojlzvta35a_execution-2kcgdj0bkm22a'
 matrixId: u'matrix-fq9ojlzvta35a'
 projectId: u'locuslabs-android-sdk'
 state: StateValueValuesEnum(VALIDATING, 1)
 testSpecification: <TestSpecification
 androidInstrumentationTest: <AndroidInstrumentationTest
 appApk: <FileReference
 gcsPath: u'gs://test-lab-bcr7j9th055js-i215tdq3ht0hw/2019-04-19_15:41:26.364106_bmag/app-debug.apk'>
 testApk: <FileReference
 gcsPath: u'gs://test-lab-bcr7j9th055js-i215tdq3ht0hw/2019-04-19_15:41:26.364106_bmag/app-debug-androidTest.apk'>
 testTargets: []>
 testSetup: <TestSetup
 account: <Account
 googleAuto: <GoogleAuto>>
 additionalApks: []
 directoriesToPull: []
 environmentVariables: []
 filesToPush: []>
 testTimeout: u'900s'>
 timestamp: u'2019-04-19T08:42:36.638Z'>]
 testMatrixId: u'matrix-fq9ojlzvta35a'
 testSpecification: <TestSpecification
 androidInstrumentationTest: <AndroidInstrumentationTest
 appApk: <FileReference
 gcsPath: u'gs://test-lab-bcr7j9th055js-i215tdq3ht0hw/2019-04-19_15:41:26.364106_bmag/app-debug.apk'>
 testApk: <FileReference
 gcsPath: u'gs://test-lab-bcr7j9th055js-i215tdq3ht0hw/2019-04-19_15:41:26.364106_bmag/app-debug-androidTest.apk'>
 testTargets: []>
 testSetup: <TestSetup
 account: <Account
 googleAuto: <GoogleAuto>>
 additionalApks: []
 directoriesToPull: []
 environmentVariables: []
 filesToPush: []>
 testTimeout: u'900s'>
 timestamp: u'2019-04-19T08:42:36.638Z'>

Test [matrix-fq9ojlzvta35a] has been created in the Google Cloud.
Firebase Test Lab will execute your instrumentation test on 1 device(s).
Creating individual test executions...done.                                                                                                                                                     

Test results will be streamed to [https://console.firebase.google.com/project/locuslabs-android-sdk/testlab/histories/bh.f0b3cb84d82b84d2/matrices/7272098978475034799].
15:42:48 Test is Pending
15:43:11 Starting attempt 1.
15:43:11 Test is Running
15:44:07 Started logcat recording.
15:44:07 Preparing device.
15:44:38 Logging in to Google account on device.
15:44:38 Installing apps.
15:44:53 Retrieving Pre-Test Package Stats information from the device.
15:44:53 Retrieving Performance Environment information from the device.
15:44:53 Started crash detection.
15:44:53 Started crash monitoring.
15:44:53 Started performance monitoring.
15:44:53 Started video recording.
15:44:53 Starting instrumentation test.
15:45:00 Completed instrumentation test.
15:45:14 Stopped performance monitoring.
15:45:29 Stopped crash monitoring.
15:45:29 Stopped logcat recording.
15:45:29 Retrieving Post-test Package Stats information from the device.
15:45:29 Logging out of Google account on device.
15:45:29 Done. Test time = 4 (secs)
15:45:29 Starting results processing. Attempt: 1
15:45:37 Completed results processing. Time taken = 4 (secs)
15:45:37 Test is Finished
INFO: Test matrix completed in state: FINISHED

Instrumentation testing complete.

More details are available at [https://console.firebase.google.com/project/locuslabs-android-sdk/testlab/histories/bh.f0b3cb84d82b84d2/matrices/7272098978475034799].
DEBUG: 
TRHistoriesExecutions.Get response:
<Execution
 completionTime: <Timestamp
 nanos: 674000000
 seconds: 1555663532>
 creationTime: <Timestamp
 nanos: 31000000
 seconds: 1555663361>
 executionId: u'7272098978475034799'
 outcome: <Outcome
 summary: SummaryValueValuesEnum(success, 4)>
 specification: <Specification
 androidTest: <AndroidTest
 androidAppInfo: <AndroidAppInfo
 name: u'FirebaseTestLabPlayground'
 packageName: u'com.example.firebasetestlabplayground'
 versionCode: u'1'
 versionName: u'1.0'>
 androidInstrumentationTest: <AndroidInstrumentationTest
 testPackageId: u'com.example.firebasetestlabplayground.test'
 testRunnerClass: u'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
 testTargets: []>
 testTimeout: <Duration
 seconds: 900>>>
 state: StateValueValuesEnum(complete, 0)
 testExecutionMatrixId: u'matrix-fq9ojlzvta35a'>

DEBUG: 
ToolResultsSteps.List response:
<ListStepsResponse
 steps: [<Step
 completionTime: <Timestamp
 nanos: 849000000
 seconds: 1555663531>
 creationTime: <Timestamp
 nanos: 232000000
 seconds: 1555663361>
 description: u'all targets'
 dimensionValue: [<StepDimensionValueEntry
 key: u'Model'
 value: u'Pixel2'>, <StepDimensionValueEntry
 key: u'Version'
 value: u'27'>, <StepDimensionValueEntry
 key: u'Locale'
 value: u'en_US'>, <StepDimensionValueEntry
 key: u'Orientation'
 value: u'portrait'>]
 labels: []
 name: u'Instrumentation test'
 outcome: <Outcome
 summary: SummaryValueValuesEnum(success, 4)>
 runDuration: <Duration
 nanos: 617000000
 seconds: 170>
 state: StateValueValuesEnum(complete, 0)
 stepId: u'bs.b2c854c31dd1dcd1'
 testExecutionStep: <TestExecutionStep
 testIssues: [<TestIssue
 category: CategoryValueValuesEnum(common, 0)
 errorMessage: u'Test is compatible with Android Test Orchestrator.'
 severity: SeverityValueValuesEnum(suggestion, 2)
 type: TypeValueValuesEnum(compatibleWithOrchestrator, 2)>]
 testSuiteOverviews: [<TestSuiteOverview
 totalCount: 1
 xmlSource: <FileReference
 fileUri: u'gs://test-lab-bcr7j9th055js-i215tdq3ht0hw/2019-04-19_15:41:26.364106_bmag/Pixel2-27-en_US-portrait/test_result_1.xml'>>]
 testTiming: <TestTiming
 testProcessDuration: <Duration
 seconds: 4>>
 toolExecution: <ToolExecution
 commandLineArguments: []
 toolLogs: [<FileReference
 fileUri: u'gs://test-lab-bcr7j9th055js-i215tdq3ht0hw/2019-04-19_15:41:26.364106_bmag/Pixel2-27-en_US-portrait/logcat'>]
 toolOutputs: [<ToolOutputReference
 output: <FileReference
 fileUri: u'gs://test-lab-bcr7j9th055js-i215tdq3ht0hw/2019-04-19_15:41:26.364106_bmag/Pixel2-27-en_US-portrait/test_cases/0000_logcat'>
 testCase: <TestCaseReference
 className: u'com.example.firebasetestlabplayground.ExampleInstrumentedTest'
 name: u'useAppContext'>>, <ToolOutputReference
 output: <FileReference
 fileUri: u'gs://test-lab-bcr7j9th055js-i215tdq3ht0hw/2019-04-19_15:41:26.364106_bmag/Pixel2-27-en_US-portrait/test_result_1.xml'>>, <ToolOutputReference
 output: <FileReference
 fileUri: u'gs://test-lab-bcr7j9th055js-i215tdq3ht0hw/2019-04-19_15:41:26.364106_bmag/Pixel2-27-en_US-portrait/video.mp4'>>, <ToolOutputReference
 output: <FileReference
 fileUri: u'gs://test-lab-bcr7j9th055js-i215tdq3ht0hw/2019-04-19_15:41:26.364106_bmag/Pixel2-27-en_US-portrait/bugreport.txt'>>, <ToolOutputReference
 output: <FileReference
 fileUri: u'gs://test-lab-bcr7j9th055js-i215tdq3ht0hw/2019-04-19_15:41:26.364106_bmag/Pixel2-27-en_US-portrait/instrumentation.results'>>]>>>]>

INFO: Display format: "
          table[box](
            outcome.color(red=Fail, green=Pass, yellow=Inconclusive),
            axis_value:label=TEST_AXIS_VALUE,
            test_details:label=TEST_DETAILS
          )
"
┌─────────┬──────────────────────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ OUTCOME │     TEST_AXIS_VALUE      │     TEST_DETAILS    │
├─────────┼──────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ Passed  │ Pixel2-27-en_US-portrait │ 1 test cases passed │
└─────────┴──────────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
FirebaseTestLabPlayground[master]15:45:45 gcloud firebase test android run --project locuslabs-android-sdk --app app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk --test app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk --device model=Pixel2,version=27,locale=en_US,orientation=portrait --verbosity debug
```

Comment: Do you know how to get testMatixId from the `gcloud firebase test android run`?

Comment: Sorry, no, @Krzysiulele